# jenkins can't locate rake installation even though path is given explicitly

Tags: ruby, linux, jenkins, rake, jenkins-plugins

EDIT: After correcting my job configuration, I now receive the following error when running this job:

```
[workspace] $ /usr/local/bin/bin/rake kickoff
/usr/bin/env: ruby: No such file or directory
Build step 'Invoke Rake' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

I am trying to set up a Jenkins server to run cucumber tests via a rake task.

I have the rake plugin installed, ruby 2.0.0 installed, and all necessary gems installed. I also have Rubygems installed.

Rake is installed here:
`/usr/local/bin/rake`

Ruby is installed here:
`/usr/local/bin/ruby`

Here is a screenshot of the Rake configuration for Jenkins:
[image]

Here is a screenshot of the Ruby configuration for Jenkins:
[image]

Despite what that warning says, Rubygems is installed to:
`/usr/local/bin/gem`

When I try to run a simple test (that just evaluates to true always), I get the following error:

```
Building in workspace /webdata/jenkins/jobs/kickoff_build/workspace
Updating https://svnprod.x.net/svn/x/trunk/inside_automation at revision '2015-07-10T09:50:36.495 -0400'
At revision 9227
no change for https://svnprod.x.net/svn/x/trunk/inside_automation since the previous build
FATAL: /usr/bin/rake doesn't exist
Build step 'Invoke Rake' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

Why is it looking for rake in /usr/bin ???? I pointed this job directly to the directory of the rake file, `/usr/local/bin/rake`?

Comment: You have `/usr/local/bin/rake` in the `Rake file` field where I think that should point to an actual Rakefile and not the binary

Comment: this is true, and the issue has been corrected, but now I get another error, which I will add to my OP

Answer (score 0):

I was able to correct this issue, and several others, by  creating a symlink to the rake executable.